# Non-canvas JavaScript Starfield animation in latest Explorer not smooth

Tags: javascript, css

The main purposes of this script are for it to be:

- Precisely resizable
- Have 'canvas like' animation smoothness
- Not interfere with anything else in a webpage, other scripts, layouts etc

All are achieved in the latest versions of Chrome and Opera. Firefox struggles with too many stars, 200+, but is adequate. However, Explorer, surprisingly, is not playing ball. I say surprisingly because when I last scripted, well over 10 years ago, IE ruled in animation.

My problem with IE is jerky expansion of oncoming stars

So far I've tried:

- scale, scale3d and height/width px
- requestAnimationFrame and setTimeout variations
- Using images in place of divs
- Removing opacity
- Lowering millisecond cycle speed and number of stars
- Removing any backgrounds, gradients etc

None of the above solve the problem.

Is it my old time scripting or Explorer or both?

Also, the script is only intended for fun hence no backwards compatibility provision.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

```js
(function () {

/* Starfield 2004 kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk (Updated) */

var v = 1.0; // Star speed
var m = 10; // Max speed 
var n = 300; // Star No
var r = 5; // 1 in 'r' stars to inner field 

//End config.

var con, dir, star, trns;
var d = document;
var cols = ['#ff6e0d', '#c4ffe8', '#fff000', '#fff56e', '#00ddff', '#ffffff'];
var depth = 2000;
var deg = 180 / Math.PI;
var rad = Math.PI / 180;
var cony = 0;
var conx = 0;
var mls = 1000 / 60;
var ini = performance.now();
var strs = [],
    starCoords = [];
var xyo = -(50 / 7);

con = d.createElement('div');
con.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;'
    +'position:absolute;' 
    +'top:0px;left:0px;'
    +'height:100%;width:100%;'
    +'margin:0px;padding:0px;'
    +'overflow:hidden;'
    +'visibility:hidden;');
d.body.appendChild(con);

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var col = cols[Math.random() * cols.length | 0];
    strs[i] = d.createElement('div');
    strs[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block;'
        +'position:absolute;'
        +'height:200px;'
        +'width:200px;'
        +'margin-top:-100px;'
        +'margin-left:-100px;'
        +'background-color:' + col + ';' 
        +'border-radius: 50%;'
        +'visibility:visible;');
    con.appendChild(strs[i]);
}

dir = d.createElement('div');
dir.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;'
    +'position:absolute;'
    +'bottom:0;right:0;'
    +'margin:3px;'
    +'height:auto;width:auto;'
    +'border:1px solid #fff;'
    +'padding:5px;letter-spacing:1px;'
    +'font:11px Verdana,Courier new;'
    +'text-align:center;color:#fff;'
    +'cursor:n-resize;opacity:0.2;'
    +'visibility:visible;');
con.appendChild(dir);
dir.innerHTML += 'Mouse Wheel<br>Velocity<br>Direction';

function scrl(a) {
    var y, x;
    y = window.pageYOffset;
    x = window.pageXOffset;
    return (a == 0) ? y : x;
}

function iniscrl() {
    con.style.top = cony + scrl(0) + 'px';
    con.style.left = conx + scrl(1) + 'px';
}

function Trnsfrm(e) {
    var t = 'Transform';
    var v;
    var vo = [t, 'Webkit' + t, 'ms' + t, 'Moz' + t, 'O' + t];
    while (v = vo.shift()) {
        if (typeof e.style[v] != 'undefined') {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
trns = Trnsfrm(d.body);

function initCoords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        star = {
            x: coords(1),
            y: coords(2),
            z: coords(),
            o: 0
        };
        starCoords.push(star);
        star.o = 1 - (0.8 * star.z / depth);
    }
}

function coords(a) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * r);
    var sel = (rnd == 0) ? 2.5 : 1.4;
    var xyz;
    if (a == 1) {
        xyz = 50 + Math.random() * 50 / sel *
            Math.sin(Math.random() * deg);
    } else if (a == 2) {
        xyz = 50 + Math.random() * 50 / sel *
            Math.cos(Math.random() * deg);
    } else {
        xyz = Math.random() * depth;
    }
    return xyz;
}

function animateCoords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        star = starCoords[i];
        star.z -= v;
        if (v >= 0) {
            if (star.z < 0) {
                star.z = depth;
                star.x = coords(1);
                star.y = coords(2);
                star.o = 0;
            }
            if (star.o < 1) {
                star.o += (v / 1000);
            }
        } else if (v < 0) {
            if (star.z > depth) {
                star.z = -1;
                star.x = coords(1);
                star.y = coords(2);
                star.o = 1.0;
            }
            if (star.z > 1000) {
                star.o += (v / 1100);
            }
        }

    }
}

function assignCoords() {
    var xpos, ypos, dims, theStars;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        star = starCoords[i];
        theStars = strs[i];
        xpos = xyo + (star.x - 50) * (depth / star.z) + deg;
        ypos = xyo + (star.y - 50) * (depth / star.z) + deg;
        dims = (1 * (depth / star.z)) / 130;
        theStars.style[trns] = 'translate3d(' + (xpos) +
            'vw, ' + (ypos) + 'vh, 0) scale3d(' + dims + ', ' +
            dims + ', 1)';
        theStars.style.opacity = star.o;
        theStars.style.zIndex = Math.round(-star.z);
    }
}

function mouseCon(e) {
    var tmp = (e.detail) ? -e.detail / 3 : e.wheelDelta / 120;
    var inc = (tmp >= 0) ? 0.5 : -0.5;
    v += inc;
    if (v < -m) {
        v += 0.5;
    }
    if (v > m) {
        v -= 0.5;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}

function draw() {
    var now = performance.now();
    if ((now - ini) > (mls)) {
        animateCoords();
        assignCoords();
        ini = performance.now();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function init() {
    initCoords();
    assignCoords();
    draw();
}

dir.onmouseout = function () {
    dir.style.opacity = 0.2;
};
dir.onmouseover = function () {
    dir.style.opacity = 1;
};

dir.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseCon, false);
dir.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseCon, false);
window.addEventListener("scroll", iniscrl, false);
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

})();
```

```css
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        body {
            background-color: #000005;
        }
```

Comment: by 'latest' do you mean ie11? looks no less smoth then firefox on my ie11. any other factors?? do you have any plugins on your ie? what's the os/ram etc?

Comment: Small note: There is usually no reason for the `ms` prefixes on many CSS properties. While IE10 did include those prefixes, they also included the standardized properties which should always be preferred (mixing the two may have bad effects)

Comment: @ Katana314 - Yes it's 'bog standard' IE11. OS is Win8.1 on ASUS i7. I tried it with just the standardized prefix - still the same. Maybe it is just my laptop which is 'straight out the box' set-up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried CSS animations?

Comment: @ Bergi - Unfortunately no. I only got back into scripting a couple of months ago. My rusty knowledge is a decade old that's why my script is good 'ole JavaScript and not canvas - which I know nothing about either! I've got a lot of catching to do.